# UK citizen living in Europe

Tags: uk-citizens

I have a Spanish residence, having recently updated my TIE. Can I work in Portugal and spend a few months there every year?

Comment: You would have to apply for a work permit to work in other European countries, for non-working visits the 90/180 rule applies.